# From where I can increase the default max deffer limit value in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, whm, exim

I am having a cPanel server , 
getting this error while sending the email .

> Domain XYZ.com has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded.

Also the maximum email sending limit is set to 500 in the tweak setting and the account package .
From where I can increase the default max deffer limit value in cpanel .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the tweak settings page, there is an option under the mail tab for: 
Number of failed or deferred messages a domain may send before protections can be triggered